# Order by date doesn't using hour and minute to order

Tags: sql, date, oracle10g

I have a select query, using a function.

The function make a substring a string, to get a date, and then order by the date, and return the string in the right order.

So I have my SELECT :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ec.id_echange_candidat,
 ( select f_tridate_concat( f_concat(iw.nom_declencheur ||' ' || iw.prenom_declencheur ||'->'||iw.nom_valideur ||' ' || iw.prenom_valideur || ' demandé le '||to_date(to_char(iw.date_creation), 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')|| ' : ' ||iw.avis), '$', 'demandé le ', ' : ', '') 
    from t_instance_workflow iw 
    where ec.id_echange_candidat = iw.id_objet ) as resume_workflow
FROM t_echange_candidat ec
```

And the function :

```
create or replace
FUNCTION F_TRIDATE_CONCAT (p_chaine VARCHAR2, p_sepFonction VARCHAR2, p_sepAvChampTri VARCHAR2, p_sepApChampTri VARCHAR2, p_sepFinal VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
     v_str VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN
  SELECT replace(f_concat(ma_chaine), '$',p_sepFinal)   INTO v_str FROM
  (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_chaine, '[^'||p_sepFonction||']+', 1, LEVEL) ma_chaine
  FROM dual
  CONNECT BY INSTR(p_chaine, p_sepFonction, 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
  ORDER BY to_date(SUBSTR(ma_chaine,instr(ma_chaine,p_sepAvChampTri,1)+length(p_sepAvChampTri),(instr(ma_chaine,p_sepApChampTri,1))-(instr(ma_chaine,p_sepAvChampTri,1)+length(p_sepAvChampTri))),'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')
  )
  ;
  RETURN v_str;
END F_TRIDATE_CONCAT;
```

The thing is, it seems it doesn't use the hours and minutes, to make its order by, so if I have this lines :

```
line 1 text ... 10/12/2013 text ... (with 11 pm in db)
line 2 text ... 10/12/2013 text ... (with 10 pm in db)
```

I will obtain this string :

```
line 1 text ... 10/12/2013 text ... 
line 2 text ... 10/12/2013 text ...
```

While I should get this :

```
line 2 text ... 10/12/2013 text ... 
line 1 text ... 10/12/2013 text ...
```

Because `lines 2 date` is in full `10/12/2013 10:00:00` while `lines 1 date` is in full `10/12/2013 11:00:00`

Why isn't it using the hours and minutes, while in my function, I use a format date like 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' in my order by?

**Edit :** Now got a "format code appears twice" error message when using to_date in my SELECT query...

It means it become :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ec.id_echange_candidat,
 ( select f_tridate_concat( f_concat(iw.nom_declencheur ||' ' || iw.prenom_declencheur ||'->'||iw.nom_valideur ||' ' || iw.prenom_valideur || ' demandé le '||iw.date_creation|| ' : ' ||iw.avis), '$', 'demandé le ', ' : ', '') 
    from t_instance_workflow iw 
    where ec.id_echange_candidat = iw.id_objet ) as resume_workflow
FROM t_echange_candidat ec  


create or replace
FUNCTION f_concat (p_input VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2
PARALLEL_ENABLE AGGREGATE USING t_f_concat;

create or replace
TYPE "T_F_CONCAT"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      AS OBJECT ( "G_STRING" 
    VARCHAR2(32767),
    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_f_concat)
    RETURN NUMBER ,

    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_f_concat,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER,
    MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_f_concat,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER,


  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_f_concat,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_f_concat)
    RETURN NUMBER
  );

create or replace
type body t_f_concat is
    STATIC FUNCTION ODCIAggregateInitialize(sctx  IN OUT  t_f_concat)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    sctx := t_f_concat(NULL);
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateIterate(self   IN OUT  t_f_concat,
                                       value  IN      VARCHAR2 )
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := self.g_string || '$' || value;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateTerminate(self         IN   t_f_concat,
                                         returnValue  OUT  VARCHAR2,
                                         flags        IN   NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    returnValue := RTRIM(LTRIM(SELF.g_string, '$'), '$');
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION ODCIAggregateMerge(self  IN OUT  t_f_concat,
                                     ctx2  IN      t_f_concat)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.g_string := SELF.g_string || '$' || ctx2.g_string;
    RETURN ODCIConst.Success;
  END;
  end;
```

Comment: Try moving your order by clause outside the subquery.

Comment: Is the first argument of `TO_DATE()` produces data exactly in the same format of your format specifier `DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS` ?

Comment: @hashbrown, to_date() produces a date object.  By definition, they have no format.

Comment: @DanBracuk I tried and it is the same result.

Comment: @DanBracuk TO_DATE() produces date object which does not have format, but the first argument of TO_DATE() function is not yet a date object, it's a string. And you need to tell database what format that string has by using the format string specifier

Comment: @hashbrown Yes, it is the same format. New bug, now I got the message "format code appears twice" when I have the format in my SELECT query.

Comment: Can you create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) of this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
WITH STRINGS
    AS (SELECT
             'Line 2' TEXT,
             '10/12/2013 10:00:00' STRING1
        FROM
             DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
             'Line 1' TEXT,
             '10/12/2013 11:00:00' STRING1
        FROM
             DUAL)
SELECT
      TEXT,
      TO_DATE ( STRING1,
              'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM
      STRINGS
ORDER BY
      TO_DATE ( STRING1,
              'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' );
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Line 2  12/10/2013 10:00:00 AM
Line 1  12/10/2013 11:00:00 AM
```

**PS:** You could have misspelled MI and MM in your conversion, which would have thrown the updated error. If you are still facing issues, provide sample inputs for the function and output you get. Also explain f_concat that is being called inside this function.

**FOLLOW UP:**

This is wrong and this is what you have in your select

```
SELECT
      TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR ( SYSDATE ),
              'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM
      DUAL;
```

**Output:**

```
1/8/2014
```

Replace it with this

```
SELECT
      TO_DATE ( TO_CHAR ( SYSDATE,
                      'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' ),
              'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM
      DUAL;
```

**Output:**

```
1/8/2014 4:36:13 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer : Where should I put this? Instead of what? Can you explain it? I check for MM and MI, and it has no errors I think. I add f_concat.

Comment: Let me the working input and output of your function F_TRIDATE_CONCAT

Comment: `Name1->Name2 demandé le 02/12/13 : Positif$Name2->Name3 demandé le 02/12/13 : Positif` While using a date formating on the date

Comment: Type body is missing in f_concat

Comment: Right. Forgot the body. Just add it.

Comment: I dont see any big hole. Can you try to print the DATE 1 and 2 you are manipulating? and post the output? It looks fine for me

Comment: Print the date? The output is `Name2->Name3 demandé le 02/12/13 : Positif$Name1->Name2 demandé le 02/12/13 : Positif` . And it works fine when there is two different date, but when it is the same, in fact it does not use the hour and minutes... When I display the full date it is for name2-> name 3 09:45:26 and 09:10:54 for the other one.

Comment: Still the same problem. I should add that, when I change date format in SQL developer option like this `DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SS` I got the good output, but the problem is, in my application, there is no such options...

Comment: Where ever you use order by use the follow up snippet. search for all TO_CHAR conversions and check their format. Also check for TRUNC if any